# How to check partial URL in express js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I am developing an app, where I invite other people. So I just wanted to skip passport auth if the url pattern matches. Here is code:

```js
const routes = (app) => {
    app.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
        if ((req.path === '/api/v2/auth/sign_up') || (req.path === '/api/v2/members/invite*'))
            next();
        else if (req.path === '/api/v2/auth/sign_in') {
            passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
                if (!user || err || info != undefined) {
                    return res.status(500).send({ message: "Something went wrong, Please try again!" });
                }
                req.user = user;
                next();
            })(req, res, next);
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
                if (!user || err || info != undefined) {
                    return res.status(500).send({ message: "Something went wrong, Please try again!" });
                }
                req.user = user;
                next();
            })(req, res, next);
        }

        app.use('/api/v2/members/invite',
            require("./memberInviteRoute"));

        app.use('/api/v2/members',
            authorize('admin', 'company'),
            require("./memberRoute"));
    });
}

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Why not just use `/api/v2/members/:inviteCode`?

Comment: Ok Brad, I will use this. So that time for checking URL I need to give `(req.path === '/api/v2/members/:inviteCode')`, is it correct?

Comment: No, what I'm asking is that rather than `app.all('/*', ...)`, why not `app.use('/api/v2/members/:inviteCode', ...)` and handle it that way?